# How do we ask for homebrew suggestions?

Tags: discussion, homebrew

I want to know if there is a good homebrew somewhere for dnd 5e. I see that we've revised our game recs policy, so I was curious how this extends to homebrewing. Is that something i can ask about here? If so, how can I ask it correctly?

To be more specific, I'd like to ask about armor rules. Most of the time, I'm just kinda wearing armor that gives me a set AC. if I wear, supposedly, boots or a hat or gloves, it doesnt matter unless they're magical. I want to find relatively balanced homebrew rules for specific slots of armor, rather than just one-covers-all

Comment: No change.  Have you read the existing meta Q&A's on homebrew: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew ?

Comment: Also, your question is too vague to answer.  "Can I ask about homebrewing?" Can you be more specific about how? All the usual site rules apply, so "list me a bunch of homebrews" obviously not...

Comment: I guess I would be looking for answers in the realm of "give me your experiences with homebrewed armor rules". I left it a little vague to avoid outright asking the question here unintentionally

Comment: @TomSterkenburg  Be specific, we're dealing with pretty broad realms here. You can mention the question on your mind, and we can tell you if it fits, and if it doesn't, guide you on how it might.

Comment: Updated with specifics

Answer (score 11):

“Give me your experience with homebrew armour rules” is not a question that would survive on the main site. It's a poll, which means every answer is equally valid, which is [one of the kinds of question not to ask here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Instead, ask about your problem, and ask it to be solved. Asking how to model armour as being location-based might make for a decent question, assuming it was written clearly enough to understand exactly what you wanted to achieve. Similarly, asking how to calculate your total AC when wearing piecemeal armour would be decent. (I can't tell what exactly your hoped-for question is, so those are just examples that might be close to what you're thinking of.)

Once asked, however, [answers will have to be from experience](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-to-deal-with-feedback-questions-about-house-rules). (Anyone can just make up an answer to a homebrew question on the spot, and we don't want dozens of people just slapping their brain-droppings onto the site with no supporting explanation of how *well* they work.) That means that you might end up waiting more or less time for an answer, since it's possible nobody has tried and tested doing what you're wanting to do.

---

The possibility that it may take a long time to get answers adds a separate, pragmatic dimension as well, which has nothing to do with “is it a question I *can* ask at RPG.se?”: are you sure you *want* to ask it here? Some questions are better off elsewhere; we're not a one-stop RPG question shop, precisely because we have rules against certain kinds of questions. If you really want to ask one of those kinds of questions, you're probably better off asking it elsewhere, right?

So practically, if you can wait for an answer, go ahead and ask it here, knowing you might not get an answer for a long time. If, practically, you really need answers now or very soon and you do just actually want people to throw untested ideas at you so you can test them yourself, then — since RPG.se is unsuited to hosting those kinds of answers and won't — you might prefer asking [in chat or on a discussion forum instead](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where untested ideas are easy to come by in large numbers.